# How to get the prodcut size attribute that the customer selected after the checkout WC

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have 2 attributions for color and size of t-shirt, I want to get the values that user selected after he creates the order

So when I check the data of the created order I don't find the related attribute of the product that the customer selected at all (btw I check through `woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta` hook )

```
function getcartitems($order_id)
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data
    $items = $order->get_items();
}
// the hook will be changed to woocommerce_checkout_order_processed
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'getcartitems');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do with the selected data, but here is how you wuld grab the values.

```
function getcartitems($order_id) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Get the items in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Get the product ID
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];

        // Get the product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

        // Get the product attribute values
        $attributes = $product->get_attributes();

        foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
            // Get the attribute name
            $attribute_name = $attribute['name'];

            // Get the attribute value(s)
            $attribute_values = $item['variation'][ "attribute_{$attribute['name']}" ];

            // Output the attribute name and value(s)
            echo "Attribute name: {$attribute_name} <br>";
            echo "Attribute values: {$attribute_values} <br>";
        }
    }
}
// the hook will be changed to woocommerce_checkout_order_processed
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'getcartitems');
```

Comment: For example if the prodict t shirt has attribute `size` and `color` e.g. size is `M` and color `black` When I print the attributes I don't find any thing related I find them as a meta values.

Comment: Which also the variations data for example select size and select color so I want to get these data of each product on the checkout that have been selected by the customer.